# Git checkout origin/master -- <folder> doesnt do the folder deletion

Tags: git, git-svn

There are some deletion happening at remote master branch, from where I have created this branch by using `git checkout -b`, but when I try to pull the changes of the remote branch by doing `git checkout origin/master -- <folder>`, it didn’t delete the folder from  the local branch.

Is there a way, I can delete the folder from the local branch, if the remote master has the folder deleted.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
git clean -df
```

Be careful though, it will remove all untracked folders! Please refer to `git clean --help` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

do you get a merge conflict? 
try this and see whether you can have the changes in remote branch

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
```

when you use the git fetch it will pull all the changes in the remote repo to the local repo.
or otherwise you could go to the master branch and then use the git pull.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin/master.
```